# How to replace NULL with value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with soccer scores. Whenever I add a score to one player it automatically adds NULL in the same row for the other players:

Like this:

```
player1 1-0, NULL, 4-1
player2 5-2, 4-1, NULL
player3 2-1, NULL, NULL
```

What I want is when I add a new score to a player, the Null should be replaced with that value (for example for player one it should be `1-0`, `4-1` and not `1-0`, `NULL`, `4-1`)

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the update statement you are using?

Comment: what is your query ? can you share it

Comment: My query is the INSERT into databasename (column) Value (Valuex);

Comment: what are your columns names? How do you represent the opponent the players in the first column?

Comment: If you want meaningful help, please post your table definition and the exact SQL query you're running.

Comment: I have a table for each player. That means that in the table "jack" I have 3 columns like I meantioned before: player 1, player 2, player3. The score 1-0 means Jack's score:1 - player1's score:0

Answer (score 3):

Even if its easy to find on the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), something like this should work...

```
UPDATE yourTable p
SET p.SomeField = p.NewValue
WHERE p.SomeField is NULL;
```

Comment: Is there something like this: "replace null if there is one, if not add the value in a new row"? This replaces only the first null and not all nulls right?

Comment: This will just replace all the `NULL`s with the value you specify on `p.NewValue` which may be a string, as well...

Answer (score 0):

In your question you seem to have three columns next to each player. Why is that? What are those columns representing?

I propose that the cells in your examples are games, and that's really what you're modelling. You should create a `game` table with columns such as `player1`, `player2`, `score1`, `score2`. That would model who played against whom, and what the respective scores were.

You could add further information to each game, for example, when the game was played.

Comment: I have a table for each player. A table(player) has a column for each player he plays against. That means I only add the scores

Comment: You can have a table for each player, to store information about them (name etc). Then have a second table representing games between those players.